# How to extract string from array with jq?

Tags: json, jq

How can I extract the value `"0.9212835072256392"` from the `value` array with jq?

```
{
  "resultType": "vector",
    "result": [
      {
        "metric": {},
        "value": [
          1608561506.684,
          "0.9212835072256392"
        ]
      }
    ]
 }
```

I tried different solutions such as `jq '.result.value[1]'`. This gives me the error message `jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index array with string "value"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use *hardcoded* index in the `value` array, you can use:

```
.result[] | .value[1]
```

[Online demo @ jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/GGLnjplglN)

---

Or, as [@vgersh99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65395098/how-to-extract-string-from-array-with-jq/65395233?noredirect=1#comment115615452_65395233) and [@ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65395098/how-to-extract-string-from-array-with-jq/65395233?noredirect=1#comment115615594_65395233) suggested, using `.value[-1]` to get the **last index**:

```
.result[] | .value[-1]
```

[Online demo @ jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/5OkInAV_dk)

Comment: or without hardwiring: ```.result[] | .value[length-1]```